# MySQL joins with one column only if values exist

Tags: mysql

I have a bunch of joins on tables in my query like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.firstnames, a.surname,b.subject_grade_id
FROM students a
LEFT JOIN student_subject b ON a.id=b.studentid
LEFT JOIN subject_grade c on b.subject_grade_id=c.id
WHERE b.subject_grade_id=?
ORDER by a.surname ASC
```

This give me a result like this:

```
id   firstnames   surname   subject_grade_id
--------------------------------------------- 
8      John        Doe           17
9      Bob         Mitchell      17
10     Mary        Smith         17
```

Now, I also have a `marks` table which I would like to join to my query. Say if the table only has one value like this:

```
id   term     studentid  subjectid   mark
--------------------------------------------- 
 1     2         8           17        25
```

and my expected output is like this:

```
id   firstnames   surname   subject_grade_id    mark
----------------------------------------------------- 
8      John        Doe           17              25
9      Bob         Mitchell      17              null
10     Mary        Smith         17              null
```

How can I achieve this?

I tried this:

```
select a.id, a.firstnames, a.surname,b.subject_grade_id,d.mark
from students a
left join student_subject b ON a.id=b.studentid
left join subject_grade c on b.subject_grade_id=c.id
outer join marks d on d.subjectid=b.subject_grade_id
WHERE b.subject_grade_id=17
ORDER by a.surname ASC
```

but it give me a result like this:

```
id   firstnames   surname   subject_grade_id    mark
--------------------------------------------------------
8      John        Doe           17              25
9      Bob         Mitchell      17              25
10      Mary        Smith         17              25
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add a condition to the `JOIN marks d` to connect it to table `a`, EG `AND a.id = d.studentid`

Answer (score 1):

Don't `OUTER JOIN` your `marks` table, `LEFT JOIN` it. The purpose of `LEFT JOIN` is to preserve rows from the right side of the join when the `ON` condition is not met, and substitute `NULL` values for the values from the left side of the join.

Comment: Thank you! I understand JOINS better now.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.id, a.firstnames, a.surname,b.subject_grade_id,d.mark
from students a
left join student_subject b ON a.id=b.studentid
left join subject_grade c on b.subject_grade_id=c.id
left join marks d on d.id=a.id  // You don't need to make join on subject Id just need to join on student id
WHERE b.subject_grade_id=17
ORDER by a.surname ASC
```

You can try above query.

Comment: I see! This worked. I understand my mistake now. Thanks so much!